# Multiple views with only one web connection?

Tags: ios, nsurlrequest

I have 3 views that need to load web pages, I am doing the following 
( with the associated connection and webview delegates ) in each of the views, is there a way to create a single source without duplicating the code in each view ?
Most solutions I have found say to use asihttp but my company discourages 3rd party components.
( I'm still learning so be kind )

```
- (void)loadPage:(NSString*)urlString
{

  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

  // Put that URL into an NSURLRequest
  NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
  // NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString     stringWithFormat:urlString]]];

  // Create a connection that will exchange this request for data from the URL
  connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req 
                                             delegate:self 
                                     startImmediately:YES];

  [self.webView loadRequest:req];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> there a way to create a single source without duplicating the code in each view ?

Maybe creating a base class containing your `loadPage` method and then deriving 3 classes from it for each of the views you need?